# jQuery implement calls through one class

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm working with COdeigniter, and I'm charging content in the main container via jQuery. I have a lot of pages and I think this isn't the best way to load it:

jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
     var home = '../Indoamericana/Administrar/callHome/';
     var info = '../Indoamericana/Intranet/information/';
     var control = '../Indoamericana/Intranet/index/Proceso/';
     var loadPage = function (page) {
         $(".page-content").load(page);
     };
     $("#start_page").click(function (event) {
         loadPage(home);
     });
     $("#informacion_general").click(function (event) {
         loadPage(info);
     });
     $("#gestion_directiva").click(function (event) {
         var process = 1;
         loadPage(control + process);
     });
         ...
 });
```

html code:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li >
        <a href="javascript:;" id = "informacion_general"> Información General </a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a href="javascript:;" id = "gestion_directiva"> Gestión Directiva </a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a href="javascript:;" id = "gestion_calidad">Sistema Gestión de la Calidad</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Can I find a better solution? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the target urls to the anchor element using a `data-*` attribute, then write a click handler for all the menu anchor elements, inside it load the content based on the `data-target` attribute

Try

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li >
        <a href="#" class = "menu-item" data-target="../Indoamericana/Administrar/callHome/"> Información General </a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a href="#" class = "menu-item" data-target="../Indoamericana/Intranet/information/"> Gestión Directiva </a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a href="#" class = "menu-item" data-target="../Indoamericana/Intranet/index/Proceso/"> Sistema Gestión de la Calidad </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

then

```
$(function() {
    $(".sub-menu .menu-item").click(function(event) {
        $(".page-content").load($(this).data('target'));  
    });
});
```